# FeathersJS express.rest api questions

Tags: express, feathersjs

I was following the documentation on FeathersJS and came across this https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/rest.html. 
Under the section of Rest and Services, the doc mentions for GET method, you can go to `/messages/1` to retrieve object with `id:1` .

I understand that this is related to the API of `express.rest()` (https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#expressrest). But I want to get a clearer picture why I could retrieve whatever object by keying in the id I want simply at `/messages/{id}/`. The doc does not paint it clear so I wonder whether is it a hidden FeatherJS api feature or part of Express concept?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the previous [services chapter](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/services.html) you can see how the `get` method is implemented on a service. All that happens with the REST adapters is that a `GET messages/{id}` will be turned into a `service.get(id)` call. For example something like

```
class SimpleService {
  async find (params) {
    return [{
      desription: '.find results'
    }]
  }

  async get(id) {
    return {
      description: `You have to do ${id}`
    }
  }
}

app.use('/messages', new SimpleService());
```

Would return `[{ description: '.find results' }]` for `GET /messages`. For `GET /messages/dishes` it would return `{ description: 'You have to do dishes' }`.

More details about the patterns behind this can be found in [Design Patterns For Modern Web APIs](https://blog.feathersjs.com/design-patterns-for-modern-web-apis-1f046635215).